# How to revive cleared highlighting in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, styles, highlighting

In Notepad++, I highlighted here and there where I needed.
Then I wanted to clear one of them, but mistakenly cleared all highlights.
I don't remember where I highlighted, so it is impossible to manually recover them.
Can I undo this clearing?

Edit: What I did in order

1. I highlighted (Right-click > Style one token > Using 1st style) Sentence A.
2. Highlighted Sentence B with 1st style
3. Highlighted Sentence C with 2nd style
4. I wanted to un-highlight Sentence C only,
   (I should have dragged Sentence C and selected 'Clear style > Clear 2nd style)
   but mistakenly selected 'Clear style > Clear all styles'

Comment: Please edit your question and add more details about what exactly you did.

Comment: @mashuptwice I added more detail.

Comment: Have you tried `Ctrl + Z`?

Comment: @Toto that doesn't seem to work for stylings